# Flutter: Ripple effect on Tab item

Tags: flutter, material-ui, tabs, tabbar

I've created a Flutter TabBar with tabs. Is there a way to add a button-like ripple effect when the user clicks on tab buttons?

```
  TabBar(
        isScrollable: true,
        controller: tabController,
        indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
        tabs: <Widget>[
          Tab(child: Text("tab 1")),
          Tab(child: Text("tab 2")),
          Tab(child: Text("tab 3"))
        ],
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

Tabs by default have the ripple effect.

```
Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Row(
      children: [
        TabBar(
          controller: tabController,
          isScrollable: true,
          indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
          tabs: <Widget>[
            Tab(child: Text("tab 1")),
            Tab(child: Text("tab 2")),
            Tab(child: Text("tab 3"))
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

[image: Preview]

EDIT:

```
Material(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: widget.onTap,
        child: Ink(
          child: Text("Tab1")
        )
      )
     )
```

If you have implemented an Inkwell for customTab you can add Ink and material to it and it will display the ripple effect.

Comment: In my case the tabs are custom-made and I need to show this effect on over tab buttons only.

Comment: It still occupies the whole area of the tab. In my case, the custom tab size is smaller and I need to have this effect only on buttons

Comment: Can you give an insight on the button size and tab size? You could make the splash colour of tab to transparent and add colour to only the button